# In Ubuntu, how can I give two groups of users root power except for access to one folder?

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, directory, permissions

I just created a Ubuntu development server and I would like to work with two teams on it. I want people from these teams to do anything they want, but I don't want them to be able to see the files from the other team, how do I do that?

If I put them in the sudo-ers file, they can access the folder from the other team, without sudo, they complaint that they aren't able to install new software on the machine. How can I give them the power they need without the ability to see the other team's files?

Comment: Don't give them sudo rights. What you want is giving someone a key without giving them a key.

Comment: Giving them the right to do *absolutely everything except one thing* is a strategy that's doomed to fail. Instead, you need to give them the right to do *everything they need to do* and nothing more.

Answer (score 2):

How about two different virtual machines, that way they each can do what they want to the system without having access to each others' files.

Answer (score 2):

You can give access to sudo on a per command basis.

add `apt-get`, starting and stopping needed daemons in `/etc/init.d` and that's it.

Comment: Sounds like exactly what the doctor ordered. http://aplawrence.com/Basics/sudo.html may be a useful tutorial to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Create two groups, and add users to each group based on the team separation.

Also, I'd create two home dirs (e.g. /home/team1 and /home/team2) and when creating users create their home dirs under each, as well as setting them to the correct group

```
useradd -D /home/team1/jsmith -g team1
```

Then implement @Hubert suggestion of restricting the 'sudo' activities.  [Sudo has tons of different configs](http://www.gratisoft.us/sudo/sudoers.man.html) it may take several back and forths with the teams to square them away.

Comment: Don't forget `umask` and `/home/{team1,team2}` permissions.